I noticed something interesting about prime numbers! $p_1+p_2 \pm 1 = p_3$
I'm young and I'm still learning a lot about mathematics, but while doing some calculations with prime numbers, I noticed a curious fact.
If you take two consecutive prime numbers and add them together, sometimes, by adding or subtracting 1 from the result, you get another prime number. Here are some examples:
5 + 7 = 12. If you add 1, you get 13, which is a prime number.
17 + 19 = 36. If you add 1, you get 37, which is a prime number.
37 + 41 = 78. If you add 1, you get 79, which is a prime number.
This doesn't always work, but it happens quite often. It seems like an interesting pattern, although I'm not sure if it's been studied before.
Does anyone know anything about this? Is it a known property, or is it just a coincidence that happens with certain prime numbers? I'd love to hear what you think!
Thanks for reading :)

Maybe the community should consider being nicer to someone "young and still learning a lot about mathematics", and making such an enthusiastic post

@BenjaminWang How are we supposed to know that the OP is "young and still learning"?

@jjagmath Sorry, I didn’t know the text had to be written in English on this site. I’m new here, and I apologize again to everyone.

Voting to reopen.  The enthusiasm is great.  Keep it up!  One thing to keep in mind while doing experiments like this is that there are a lot of small primes.  If you only experiment with small numbers you can get the false impression that all sorts of things give rise to primes.  Most of the time, it's an accident of small numbers.

@lulu Thank you for giving me an answer. I figured my proposal might not be correct, but I wanted to ask just in case.

Maybe surprisingly, it turns out that a prime is "equally likely" (in some definable sense) to have any desired non-zero remainder  on division by some fixed prime. So, for instance, the probably that a prime has the form $5k+2$ is $\frac 14$, again in a way which can be made precise.  Similarly the probability that a prime has the form $5k+4$ is $\frac 14$, so the probability that $p+q-1$ is divisible by $5$ is greater than $\frac 1{16}$, for example.

@alessiobennardo Keep up the enthusiasm! May your love for math never fade :)

@alessiobennardo Data for the first billion primes shows that proportion of prime pairs for which this holds approches zero. So you obsrvation is basically a small number's bias

The observation likely reflects the fact that prime numbers $\ge 5$ have the form $6n\pm 1$. For $p_1=6a\pm 1$ and $p_2=6b\pm 1$, their sum is $6(a+b)\pm c$ where $c\in \{-2,0,2\}$. Thus the sum is within $1$ of at least one number of the form $6(a+b)\pm 1$. Especially at low values of $p_i,p_2$ the sum is of a magnitude where prime numbers of the form $6n\pm 1$ are more common, the happy event that $p_1+p_2\pm 1$ is prime is not rare. If OP wanted to test his hypothesis, he could work with much larger primes (say $>1000$) and determine whether the happy accident happens less frequently.
